# Show that $\Phi(f) : x \mapsto \int_0^1 \min\{x,t\}f(t)dt$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ where $f \in \mathcal{C}([0;1], \mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show that $\Phi(f) : x \mapsto \int_0^1 \min\{x,t\}f(t)dt$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$ where $f \in \mathcal{C}([0;1], \mathbb{R})$, and calculate $\Phi(f)'$ and $\Phi(f)''$.

I don't know how to show that $\Phi(f)$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, and don't know how to find the derivative of $\min\{x,t\}f(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We compute

$$ \Phi(f)(x) = \int_0^1 \min\{x,t \}f(t)dt = \int_0^x t\cdot f(t)dt + \int_x^1 x\cdot f(t) dt. $$

Apply Leibniz's integral rule tells us that the RHS is differentiable and that we can differentiating under the integral sign, which yields

$$ \Phi(f)'(x)= x\cdot f(x) - x\cdot f(x)+ \int_x^1 f(t)dt = \int_x^1 f(t)dt. $$

Applying Leibniz's integral rule again tells us that the RHS is differentiable. Differentiating under the integral sign to get your second derivative

$$ \Phi(f)''(x)=-f(x).$$

As $f$ is continuous, we get that $\Phi(f)$ is $C^2$.

Edit: As it has been pointed out in the comment section, in order to apply Leibniz integral rule one needs to check that the $t\cdot f(t)$, $\partial_x (t\cdot f(t)) \ (=0)$, $x\cdot f(t)$ and $\partial_x (x\cdot f(t)) \ (=f(t))$ are continuous (with respect to both variables). However, $f(t),x$ and $t$ are continuous functions with respect to $x$ and $t$ and so are their products.

Comment: Thank you so much! But, I dont understand this line $\Phi(f)(x) = \int_0^1 \min\{x,t \}f(t)dt = \int_0^x t\cdot f(t)dt + \int_x^1 x\cdot f(t) dt.$ Why is $\int_0^1 \min\{x,t\}$ becoming that? How to show that?

Comment: Because, if you integrate from $0$ to $x$, then $0\leq t\leq x$. Thus, $\min\{ x,t\}=t$. On the other hand, if you integrate from $x$ to $1$, you have $x\leq t\leq 1$ and hence $\min\{ x, t\}=x$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would say that you haven't shown that $\Phi$ is differentiable in the first place.  Of course, the theorems that allow you to find the derivative would in turn describe $\Phi$ as a composition of differentiable functions.  That being said, it seems like an explicit reference to the *existence* of the derivative should be made.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That depends on your interpretation of the term "differentiate under the integral sign". If you understand this as "apply Leibniz integral rule" (as I do), then my answer worked perfectly fine. How do you understand it? I edited it nonetheless to be perfectly accurate :)

Comment: Again, I wouldn't say that the Leibniz rule directly states that your function is differentiable. It does say that such a function is differentiable *if we also know that the integrand is continuous*, which would require some separate observation. Depending on one's taste, that might be the sort of thing that one can take for granted.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah, now I see your point. Thank you very much. This is of course something one should mention.